# Put a Google Chrome browser action on the side of a window

Tags: javascript, browser, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I've written some very simple code (a Google Chrome extension) that gets the keywords from a Google search and display it on a browser action. (I can put the code if necessary).

The thing is for practical reasons I'd like the browser action to be displayed on the side of the browser (like a sidebar).

Is it possible to do this ? I've been searching and so far haven't found.

Comment: Do you mean you'd like to alter the current page displayed? If so, content scripts that are injected in the current page might help you.

Comment: @pimvdb I don't think it would work because I need to use Google Chrome Api and with content script I wouldn't be able to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browser Actions can only ever appear in the top right of the screen next to the Omnibox (url bar).  You can't change where they appear.

If you want to create something that appears on the right of the browser, you can create a content script that will allow you to inject your own HTML, CSS and JS in to any page that the user navigates too. Using this can could create a menu or popup that is anchored to the left or right of the screen.

Conent scripts don't have direct access to most of the `chrome.*` namespace, but you can easily use [message passing](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/messaging.html) to talk to your background page (which has full access) and get it to return results to your content script.

Comment: I don't think it would work because I need to use Google Chrome Api and with content script I wouldn't be able to use it.

Comment: @Bruno, of course you can.  Read into message passing. http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/messaging.html - that is how you use full Chrome API's via a content script.